# Java Income Tax Calculator need to add prompt to add more customers

Tags: java

I have a java program that calculates users' income taxes, with some help the project now runs correctly, but I am supposed to add an option for the user to process additional customers once they have finished with a customer by entering 'y' into a prompt. I need the prompt to say:    "Process another customer? (y/n)?" Since the user could also hit "n" this prompt will also have to have a command for both 'y' and 'n' how and where do I do this and where do I  need to put the prompt in my code? here is my code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final double RATE1 = 0.20;
        final double RATE2 = 0.25;
        final double RATE3 = 0.10;
        final double RATE4 = 0.15;
        final double RATE5 = 0.30;
        final double RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 20000;
        final double RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 50000;
        double tax = 0;

        //Enter Income
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter your income: ");
        double income = in.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
        String maritalStatus = in.next();

        //Calculate Taxes

        if (maritalStatus.equals("s") && income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE1 * income;
        }else if (maritalStatus.equals("m") && income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE2 * income;
        }else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE3 * income;
        }else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE4 * income;
        } else {
            tax= RATE5 * income;
        }

        System.out.print("Your tax is: " + tax);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need a loop, for example a while or do/while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of a `do...while` loop.
[The while and do-while Statements | Java Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxCalculator {
    static void calculate() {

        final double RATE1 = 0.20;
        final double RATE2 = 0.25;
        final double RATE3 = 0.10;
        final double RATE4 = 0.15;
        final double RATE5 = 0.30;
        final double RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT = 0;
        final double RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 20000;
        final double RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT = 50000;
        double tax = 0;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        //Enter Income
        System.out.print("Please enter your income: ");
        double income = in.nextDouble();
        in.nextLine();

        System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
        String maritalStatus = in.next();
        in.nextLine();

        //Calculate Taxes

        if (maritalStatus.equals("s") && income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE1 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("m") && income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE2 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE3 * income;
        } else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
            tax = RATE4 * income;
        } else {
            tax = RATE5 * income;
        }

        System.out.print("Your tax is: " + tax);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String newResponse = "";
        do {
            calculate();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Process another response?. Please enter 'y' for yes, or 'n' for no: ");
            newResponse = in.next();
            in.nextLine();
        } while (newResponse.equals("y"));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the end of your program, after you display the tax of the first user you can ask if there is a new user or no, if yes you will repeat the same steps as for the first user and if no your program will finish, to do that you must first add a boolean variable (or integer as you want), to know if there is a new user or no:

```
boolean newCustomer = false;
```

then your entire code will be inside a do while loop as following:

```
do{
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Please enter your income: ");
double income = in.nextDouble();

System.out.print("Please enter 's' for single, 'm' for married, or 'c' for cohabitating: ");
String maritalStatus = in.next();

//Calculate Taxes

if (maritalStatus.equals("s") && income > RATE1_SINGLE_LIMIT) {
    tax = RATE1 * income;
}else if (maritalStatus.equals("m") && income > RATE2_MARRIED_LIMIT) {
    tax = RATE2 * income;
}else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE3_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
    tax = RATE3 * income;
}else if (maritalStatus.equals("c") && income <= RATE4_COHABITATING_LIMIT) {
    tax = RATE4 * income;
} else {
    tax= RATE5 * income;
}

System.out.println("Your tax is: " + tax);

    System.out.print("Please type 'y' for a new customer, or 'n' to finish the program : ");
    String customer = in.next();
    if(customer.equals("y"))
        newCustomer = true;
    else
        newCustomer = false;
}
while(newCustomer);
```